# Unable to edit or replace deployment {deploymentName}: previous deployment from {datetime} is still active (expiration time is {datetime})

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Bicep template with

```bash
az deployment sub create --name "deploymentName" --template-file template.json --location="westeurope" --parameters ...
```

When I go to Azure Portal to review my resource group deployments I can see this error message: *Unable to edit or replace deployment {deploymentName}: previous deployment from {datetime} is still active (expiration time is {datetime})*

[image]

And, If I access to the wrong deployment I can't see any error. Azure says *Your deployment is complete.*

[image]

What's wrong? This error occurs intermittently, on different resources each time. We need delete the wrong deployments many times to make it works.

I reviewed my Azure Bicep template and all resources contains the depends_on clause in order to avoid concurrency issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is crucial to ensure your deployments (in other words bicep modules) have unique names in runtime.

You generate a bicep module name using the current DateTime and probably reuse it within the main deployment. The code below shows an idea of what happens to you (`secrets` and `secrets2` modules end up with the same name):

```
param now string = utcNow('u')

module secrets 'resources/common/secrets.bicep' = {
  name: 'kv-${now}'
}

/* another bicep file within the same main deployment */    

param now string = utcNow('u')

module secrets2 'resources/common/secrets.bicep' = {
  name: 'kv-${now}'
}
```

I would not recommend relying on dates, since deployments must be idempotent. Instead use paramers or variables that provide context where the module is reused. For example, `systemShortName`:

```
param systemShortName string = 'sql-secrets'

module secrets 'resources/common/secrets.bicep' = {
  name: 'kv-${systemShortName}'
}

/* another bicep file within the same main deployment */ 

param systemShortName string = 'storageaccount-secrets'

module secrets2 'resources/common/secrets.bicep' = {
  name: 'kv-${systemShortName}'
}
```